# How can I get values while moving device in x coordinate system

Tags: android, device, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I need a sensor, which will give me values while moving device from west to east and from east to west, while I don't rotate a device.
In other words, a sensor, that will measure a displacement of a device, from left to right as a result of hand movement.

Comment: Use the accellerometers.

Comment: Is there some papers with the formula?

Comment: The formulas you can find in your physics course. v=at. s=1/2at^2.